# Prolog Recursive Predicates

Tags: recursion, prolog, predicates

Give recursive definition in Prolog:
Define a predicate that holds of an argument X if and only if X
is a list and the length of X is odd.

I have been trying to solve this for ages. I am just wanting to learn ProLog for myself and found this problem in a book.

I have tried this but it probably only works for lists of even length.

```
mult2_length( [] ).
mult2_length( [ _, _ | Xs ] ) :-
  mult2_length( Xs ).
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Can you post something you have tried that doesn't work? You will get more help more quickly if you do.

Comment: @Nick I have edited it to show what I have done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have predicates like these:

```
list([]) :- fail.
list([_]).
list([_,_|T]) :- list(T).
```

You just keep removing 2 elements from list until there are 0 or 1.

Comment: The clause `list([]) :- fail.` can be removed. As no other clause matches the empty list, a call `list([])` will fail anyway.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie Of course, but I found my code more understandable for new prolog users, that's why I wrote the line after lines of code :)

Comment: That's what I guessed. IMHO it's important for beginners to learn that whatever isn't explicitly defined to suceed will fail, but you may see it differently.